# Parse html using Perl works for 2 lines but not multiple

Tags: html, perl

I have written the following Perl script-

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<<END_HTML);

<span class=time>1 h </span> 
<a href="http://foo.com/User">User</a>: There are not enough <b>big</b>
<b>fish</b> in the lake ;
END_HTML

my $source   = "foo";
my @time     = "10-14-2011";
my $name     = $html->find('a')->as_text;  
my $comment  = $html->as_text;
my @keywords = map { $_->as_text } $html->find('b');
```

Which outputs- `foo, 10-14-2011, User, 1h User: There are not enough big fish in the lake, big fish`
Which is perfect and what I wanted from the test html but
this only works fine when I put in the aforementioned HTML, which I did for test purposes.

However the full HTML file has multiple references of 'a' and 'b' for instances therefore when printing out the results for these columns are blank.

How can I account for multiple values for specific searches?

Comment: Can you add a link to the full HTML file?

Comment: could you elaborate please @mob ? I could post a larger chunk of the html?

Comment: `$html->warn(1)` turns on warnings about syntax errors in the source HTML. Use it to rule out the possibility that your code doesn't work because the input is flaky.

Comment: right I have sorted my original problem, however how could I create a new line after every new comment? It is coming out as one massive line

Comment: @Jambo: you should be able to edit your question.

Comment: @Jambo: do you mean an HMTL `<!-- ... -->` comment? Please add to your question; that way you can explain yourself better and it will be bumped to the top of the queue and so get more attention.

Comment: I have added to my answer, and hope I have understood your new question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sight of your real HTML it is hard to help, but `$html->find` returns a list of `<a>` elements, so you could write something like

```
foreach my $anchor ($html->find('a')) {
  print $anchor->as_text, "\n";
}
```

But that will find *all* `<a>` elements, and it is unlikely that that is what you want. $html->look_down() is far more flexible, and provides for searching by attribute as well as by tag name.

I cannot begin to guess about your problem with comments without seeing what data you are dealing with.

---

If you need to process each text element independently then you probably need to call the `objectify_text` method. This turns every text element in the tree into a pseudo element with a `~text` tag name and a `text` attribute, for instance `<p>paragraph text</p>` would be transformed into `<p><~text text="paragraph text" /></p>`. These elements can be discovered using `$html->find('~text')` as normal. Here is some code to demonstrate

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(<<END_HTML);

<span class=time>1 h </span> 
<a href="http://foo.com/User">User</a>: There are not enough <b>big</b>
<b>fish</b> in the lake ;
END_HTML

$html->objectify_text;
print $_->attr('text'), "\n" for $html->find('~text');
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 h 

User
: There are not enough 
big

fish
 in the lake ;
```